# Value assignment issues with java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming and I was playing round with a code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte x = 10;
        x = x*10;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

This gives a compilation error and I know why. But what I don`t understand is why the code below does not give an error:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte x = 10;
        x *= 10;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

From what I know

```
    x *= x;
```

and

```
   x = x*x;
```

are same.

What am I missing then?

Answer (score 0):

The compound assignment operators will perform automatic type-casting. You could find more details on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compound-assignment-operators-java/